# Track object of certain shape and color from Webcam for beginner in CV

Tags: computer-vision

I want to track objects of simple shapes and rather homogeneous colors. I would like to do it more or less by myself, with minimum copy-paste. Does anyone know any good book/course/set of tutorials to computer vision?

Preferred platform is .net, but if materials are general enough it is fine.

Thanks,
Andrey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamentals of the application you're interested in developing can be found in any introductory computer vision book.

You can take a look at Richard Szeliski's book which is available online and is very good: http://szeliski.org/Book/

Computer Vision: A Modern Approach is another introductory book to computer vision.